# Using LODs on many objects in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to use LOD groups in my(mobile) game, because I have problems with performance. The thing is that I have seen it used on objects that are not in big amount(like cars in racing game), but I think that my game would most benefit from using it on terrain(not unity terrain system, just some terrain parts like rocks etc.). The problem is that I don't know if it is meant to be used on this many objects(I have a lot of them in the scene). The other thing is how would baked lightmaps work on these(is it even possible)?

Comment: Be careful developing for mobile because you have limited resources. Also high level graphics will consume the battery really fast. I suggest you to view some tutorials about mobile development.

Comment: I don't think the number of objects you use LOD on is relevant. However, why don't you simply try it out with a Profiler attached? About the lighing: you might simply use light probes instead of lightmaps for your LOD terrain objects.